# Crystal reports not showing all parameters

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Crystal reports is not showing all parameters when I run code in vb.net but I can view them all on preview.

I am using three dynamic parameters as; `Location_Code.Location, Location_Code.Category and Location_Code.Item_Type.` `Location.Location_Code` is the one not showing all the values.

Another report on the same application with the same dynamic parameter `Location.Location_Code` is working fine.

Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Location.Location_Code` is not in your original dynamic parameter list of three. Is there any error? If not can you show what you mean by *not showing all parameters when I run code in vb.net*

Comment: The values of the later parameters are selected based on the values selected first. Location.Location_Code is in my original dynamic parameters and there is no error. What I mean is not all the values of location in my database show when I run the program, but I can view all of them in the preview section of crystal reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the registry to increase the rows values

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV]
"MaxRowsetRecords"="500000"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Suite XI 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV]
"MaxRowsetRecords"="500000"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV]
"MaxRowsetRecords"="500000"

Comment: I added the registry key but its still not working. I even added this in the app config: <add key="maxNumberListOfValues" value="10000"/> I don't know if it was the right thing to do but I just can't figure out what is wrong here... Thank you.

Comment: Additionally, I only have the last registry. Am I supposed to manually add the other two too?

Comment: Yes u need add all the three of them

Comment: I am adding all the keys to the server but its still not working. Am I missing something else here?

Comment: I updated at both ends but the values are still not showing.

Comment: how many records u have?? update the crystal report viewer that might solve ur issue

Comment: I have 1, 216 records... Thanks, I'll try that